# Cable test G pin light up together with pin 5

Tags: cable, cat7

I'm testing my cat7 cable with a cable tester. Pin 1-8, then G light up one by one. But when at pin 5, both pin 5 and G light up at the same time. Does that mean there is a short circuit between my cable 5 and the shielding?

I'm using NS-468 tester with T-568B standard

Comment: Both ends of the cable are unplugged, yes?

Comment: What does the cable tester manual say?

Comment: Could be that you damaged the cable while stripping the isolation. Reterminate the plugs and check again. If the error persists, Change the cable.